# Powershell: Why does System.Net.WebClient fail on the third openRead for the same host

Tags: powershell, webclient, powershell-4.0

I have created a Powershell-script that checks a bunch of URL's. Below is the code snippet that uses the WebClient to read from the list of url's one by one.

```
try {
    $log.debugFormat("Now checking endpoint={0}", $checkUrl)
    $wc.OpenRead($checkUrl)
    $log.infoFormat("guid={0} loop={1} endpoint={2} status=success", ($guid, $i, $checkUrl))
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    $log.errorFormat("guid={0} Could not connect to {1}", ($guid, $checkUrl))
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $log.errorFormat("{0}", $ErrorMessage)
```

The strange thing is that it times out on every third attempt for every single host I provide. First I spent hours troubleshooting the webserver configuration just to realize now that it is the Webclient itself that somehow times out when trying to connect to the same host the third time.

I have tried to add `$wc.Dispose()` and also tried to create the object each time in the loop `$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient`, but no help.

Version is `Powershell -Command "Write-Host $psversiontable.psversion"` 4.0, on Windows 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the stream, something like:

```
$stream = $wc.OpenRead($checkUrl)
$stream.Close()
```

Disposing `WebClient` is also good idea

Comment: Magic, added `$stream.close()` and `$wc.dispose()` in a `finally`-block, that did solve the issue.